# How to increment the value of jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors, jsonp

Consider the following Jquery Ajax looping a PHP script. I have a few problems with it because it appends the first div with content from server but the rest of the divs are empty, i guess that's because of duplicated IDs

1st Question . As this is possible,

```
$("<span id='name" + counter + "'></span>")
```

as you can see, I'm adding "1" to the id "#name" every time it's appended, so the first span's id is "name1" and follows "name2 and so on"

i also want to increment this selector:

$('#name').html(feedback.name)

e.g, the first selector should be 
    $('#name1').html(feedback.name)

and the second be, 
    $('#name2').html(feedback.name)

and so on.
what's the right syntax for that?

2nd Question:

Consider this.

```
$("<span id='name" + counter + "'></span>")
```

is there anyway i can load that div from somewhere else and achieve the same results as below without going through same origin policy issues? If JSONP will help please suggest some structure i can use.

Full Jquery Ajax Code:

```
var get_fb = (function(){
    var counter = 0;
    var $buzfeed = $('#BuzFeed');
    return function(){
        $.ajax({
            dataType : 'json',
            type: "GET",
            url: "Algor.php"
        }).done(function(feedback) {
            counter += 1;
            var $buzfeedresults = 
$("<span id='name" + counter + "'></span>");
            $('#name').html(feedback.name); 
            $buzfeedresults.append(feedback);
            $buzfeed.append($buzfeedresults);
            var $buzfeedDivs = $buzfeed.children('div');
            if ($buzfeedDivs.length > 7) { $buzfeedDivs.last().remove(); }
            setTimeout(get_fb, 2000);
        })
    };
})();
get_fb();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already answered your first question? It is the same as what you already did. Second question, no I don't think you can.

Comment: no that doesn't work.

Comment: `$('#name' + counter);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
// selects all 'span' elements, that have an 'id' attribute,
// which starts with the string 'name':
$('span[id^="name"]').filter(function(){
    // filters that collection, tests to see whether the 'id' follows the
    // starts-with 'name', ends-with one or more numbers, with nothing between:
    return /^name\d+$/.test(this.id);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8xGAW/1/).

References:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`RegExp.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FRegExp%2Ftest).

Comment: i'm a bit of a student here, can you please incorporate the full code into that? please.